# most frequent word of a csv file column mapred python

Tags: python, mapreduce

do someone know how create a mapred python script that shows the most frequent word of a csv column?
for example csv file has column A, B, C.  I want the script to output the most frequent word of column C, any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To easily work with csv you could use the library `pandas`. To count the occurrences, try with `collections`

```py
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter

df = pd.read_csv("csv_path") # Load the csv into a dataframe
occurrences = Counter(df['C']) # Count every word for the 'C' column.

# Now you have a dictionary-like structure with words as keys, and the number of occurrences as the value.
# If you want only the most frequent, you could use :

most_used_word = max(occurrences, key=occurrences.get)
```

Comment: Hi @TennyKs, thanks a lot for your feedback, here's how my code looks like: I'm getting a very long output from this code if you can suggest a solution to only get the most frequent value in column 10 that would be very helpful:              #!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
from collections import Counter

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split(',') # split line into parts
    occurrences = Counter(columns[10])
    most_used_pm = occurrences.most_common(1)
    print(most_used_pm)